# Exception in removing item from array list in recycler view

Tags: android

I wrote some code for removing items from a recycler view objects. That is inside an array list 
It works until the size and the index become equal or index become bigger. I really can't find the problem

```
public void deleteSelectedItems(){
    if (selectedItemList.size() < 1)
        return;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < selectedItemList.size() ; i++){
        int index = selectedItemList.get(i) ;
        Log.e("AAA",index + "");
        guitaristsList.remove(index);
    }
    selectedItemList.clear();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
```

}

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        if (isOnActionMode) {

            if (chxDelete.isChecked())
                selectedItemList.add(getAdapterPosition());
            else
                selectedItemList.remove((Object)getAdapterPosition());

            if (onCheckboxClickListener != null)
                onCheckboxClickListener.onCheckboxCheckedChanged(selectedItemList.size());
        }
```

}

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.amehrvarz.mycontextual, PID: 12492
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 1
    at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:503)
    at com.amehrvarz.mycontextual.GuitaristAdapter.deleteSelectedItems(GuitaristAdapter.java:120)
    at com.amehrvarz.mycontextual.MainActivity$3.onActionItemClicked(MainActivity.java:71)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl$ActionModeCallbackWrapperV9.onActionItemClicked(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:2452)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.WindowDecorActionBar$ActionModeImpl.onMenuItemSelected(WindowDecorActionBar.java:1123)
    at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:840)
    at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:158)
    at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:991)
    at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:981)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:625)
    at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:151)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
    at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 12492 SIG: 9

Comment: Are you sure `selectedItemList.get(i)` always returns a valid index that you can remove from `guitaristsList `? Could you also post here full stack trace of the exception you get? It would help us to help you.

Comment: I added @JeneaVranceanu

Comment: When I delete early items it will be deleted until last item . But when i delete latest items it get throw exception after 4 - 5 delete

Comment: Looks like `int index = selectedItemList.get(i)` does not give you right index you need. Or `guitaristsList` is modified in some other place before you start to remove elements from it. Another question: could you post the code where you add elements to `selectedItemList`?

Comment: The problem could be that indices you store in `selectedItemList` are wrong values.

Comment: @JeneaVranceanu  I added the item inside recyclerview viewholder

Comment: @JeneaVranceanu I think it's because the for loop. I changed the whole logic of adding and removing and it works . Instead of storing number as integer I store the object and I removed the object directly. But still I want to know what is the problem with the above code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215355/discussion-between-jenea-vranceanu-and-jprogrammer).